# Subquery in LINQ to Entities

Tags: linq-to-entities

I have a working query in LINQ to SQL. I need to convert it into LINQ to Entities.

```
(from pr in Products
join c in Categories on pr.CategoryID equals c.CategoryID
join b in Colors on pr.ColorID equals b.ColorID
select new{
ProductID = pr.ProductID,
Manufacturer = pr.Manufacturer.Name,
Model = v.Model.ModelName,
Category = c.Name,
Photos = from p in Photos where pr.ProductID == p.ProductID select p
}).FirstOrDefault()
```

When I use it as it is I get an error:

> Unable to create a constant value of type Only primitive types ('such
>   as Int32, String, and Guid') are supported in this context.

The problem is in this part:

```
Photos = from p in Photos where pr.ProductID == p.ProductID select p
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved it in a very easy way - I divided that query into 2 methods:

```
GetAllProducts()
GetAllPhotos()
```

and than joined the result through ProductsDTO that has all the properties from both queries.

Answer (score 1):

LINQ to Entities auto-manages related queries for you (assuming all of your keys/relationships are defined properly).

Try this:

```
(from pr in Products
select new{
ProductID = pr.ProductID,
Manufacturer = pr.Manufacturer.Name,
Model = pr.Color.Model.ModelName,
Category = pr.Category.Name,
Photos = pr.Photos
}).FirstOrDefault()
```

Also see this article (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896321.aspx)